# Replace a string with the middle section of that string in csv with Python

Tags: python

I'm trying to replace a string in the first column of a csv and have been running into some issues, namely an 'AttributeError: NoneType object has no attribute group' error.  When using code like this as a test things work fine.
```

```
import re

array = [['aaa-bbb-ccc_dddL_eee_V00T00000-00_00000_V00T00000-00_00000_ACK_00000000.XML', '907 ', 'Sep 13 2018  18:07', ' '], ['V11T11111-11_11111_V11T11111-11_11111_ACK_11111111.XML', '875','Jan 31 2018  00:00',' ']]

print(array, end='\n\n')

for item in array:
    m = re.search(r'(\D\d+\D\d+\-\d+)', item[0])
    print(m.group(),end='\n\n')
    item[0] = m.group()
    print(item,end='\n\n')
```

```

But when trying to implement this in a script that opens a csv that would have an array of a similar structure (just many more arrays in the array) I receive the NoneType error.

```

```
with open('./input.csv', 'r') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    for row in read`enter code here`er:
        m = re.search(r'(\D\d+\D\d+\-\d+)', row[0])
        row[0] = m.group()
```

```

I not quite sure why things don't work with the second implementation since I am indeed getting matches in the csv.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.  Thanks.

Comment: `enter code here` ?

Comment: `re.search` will return `None` if no match is found, so my guess is that some of your data don't match your regex.

Comment: put a `if m:` just above `row[0] = m.group()`

Comment: To narrow down the problem I would test if `m is None` and whenever that happens do `print(row)` to understand which lines in the CSV file don't match

Comment: Thanks @caot that did the trick for me!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When using re.search, when no match is found, the function returns None and when that happens, your code translates to None.group() which is the error you are seeing. To fix that, check whether search found anything first:

```
import re

array = [['aaa-bbb-ccc_dddL_eee_V00T00000-00_00000_V00T00000-00_00000_ACK_00000000.XML', '907 ', 'Sep 13 2018  18:07', ' '], ['V11T11111-11_11111_V11T11111-11_11111_ACK_11111111.XML', '875','Jan 31 2018  00:00',' ']]

print(array, end='\n\n')

for item in array:
    m = re.search(r'(\D\d+\D\d+\-\d+)', item[0])
    if m:
        print(m.group(),end='\n\n')
        item[0] = m.group()
        print(item,end='\n\n')
```

Comment: Thanks @danilo-souza-moraes

Comment: if this answered you question, can you please accept it?